# HTML call method in controller by button click

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm building an ASP.Net MVC5 EF6 application in Visual studio.

I have 2 models, one is the student model with attribute StudentID, FullName, Email and ProgramStatus.
I also have a screening test model with attributes Student, MathsMark and EnglishMark.

In my Details view (code can be found below) I would like to add a button for a user to click on, which will call up a method in the controller called acceptStudent which sends an email and updates the Student's ProgramStatus to 'Accepted'.

I am really struggling to figure out how to call that method. 
My latest attempt can be found below, It doesn't work though.

Any references to instructions or helpful answers are very much appreciated!

```
@model AEC.Models.ScreeningTestRecord

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Screening Test Results</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Below are the results of the student's screening test.</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Student.FullName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Student.FullName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MathsMark)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MathsMark)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EnglishMark)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EnglishMark)
        </dd>



</dl>
    @Html.BeginForm("acceptStudent", "ScreeningTestRecord", new { id = model.Id }, FormMethod.Post) 
    <input type="submit" value="edit" name="edit" />

    </div>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.StudentID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") |
    </p>
```

Comment: Get rid of the `<%=` and `%>`

Comment: People prefer razor syntax

Comment: @StephenMuecke I removed them. Now when I click the button, I get an exception which says 'The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present. '

Comment: That would be because you controller method is decorated with the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute - you need to add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` inside your `<form>` element

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("acceptStudent", "ScreeningTestRecord", new { id = model.Id }, FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <button type="submit">Accept Student</button>
    }
```